# Nested For loops: Remove identical polygons from list of polygons

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of polygons and a function that checks if two polygons are identical. My problem is i want to add only one of the n number of identical polygons found in this list. If the polygon is unique, then it gets added to the unique list. How can I tweak my following code to do this:

```
    Dim bIdentical As Boolean = False
    Dim bTwinAdded As Boolean = False
    For Each outerEle As clsElement In liAllPolygons
        'bTwinAdded = False
        bIdentical = False
        For Each innerEle As clsElement In liAllPolygons
            If outerEle.Equals(innerEle) Then Continue For
            If ClsMath.AreTwoPolygonsIdentical2(outerEle.Nodes, innerEle.Nodes) Then
                bIdentical = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Not bIdentical Then liUniquePolygons.Add(outerEle)
        If bIdentical AndAlso Not bTwinAdded Then
            liUniquePolygons.Add(outerEle)
            bTwinAdded = True
        End If
```

I simply can't think what I can do. Given in a list of 10 polygons, number 3 ,4 are identical and number 9, 10 are identical, then the list liUniquePolygons should get only number 3 and number 9 and the rest of the list in it. With the above code, number all polygons except number 4, 9 and 10 get added.

Edit:

1) This way throws the Index Out Of Range Exception, as the number of list members has decreased.

```
For outerCount As Integer = 0 To liAllPolygons.Count - 1
        'bTwinAdded = False
        bIdentical = False
        For innerCount As Integer = 0 To liAllPolygons.Count - 1
            If liAllPolygons(outerCount).Equals(liAllPolygons(innerCount)) Then Continue For
            If ClsMath.AreTwoPolygonsIdentical2(liAllPolygons(outerCount).Nodes, liAllPolygons(innerCount).Nodes) Then
                liAllPolygons.RemoveAt(innerCount)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

2) This throws the exception that List Has Changed:

```
 For Each outerEle as clsElement in liAllPolygons
        'bTwinAdded = False
        bIdentical = False
        For Each innerEle as clsElement in liAllPolygons
            If outerEle .Equals(innerEle ) Then Continue For
            If ClsMath.AreTwoPolygonsIdentical2(outerEle .Nodes, innerEle.Nodes) Then
                liAllPolygons.Remove(innerEle)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will produce a List of unique objects based on the comparison made by your function AreTwoPolygonsIdentical2.

This does seem a bit wasteful, but it should work...

```
For Each outerEle In liAllPolygons

        'Compare outerEle  to all other items and see if there are identical matches
        Dim isIdentical As Boolean = False 'set a flag to indicate a match was found

        For Each innerEle In liAllPolygons

            If outerEle.Equals(innerEle) Then Continue For 'ignore the innerEle that is literaly the same as the outerEle

            'if the innerEle and outerEle are the same
            If ClsMath.AreTwoPolygonsIdentical2(innerEle.Nodes, outerEle.Nodes) Then
                'this item is not a unique item
                isIdentical = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        If Not isIdentical Then
            'if the item is unique, add it to the unique items list
            liUniquePolygons.Add(outerEle)
        Else
            'the item has a twin, we need to look at our list of unique items and see if we've already added the match
            Dim isMatchAdded As Boolean = False
            For Each uniqueEle In liUniquePolygons
                If ClsMath.AreTwoPolygonsIdentical2(uniqueEle.Nodes, outerEle.Nodes) Then
                    isMatchAdded = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            'we have nomatching items in the list, add it in
            If Not isMatchAdded Then
                liUniquePolygons.Add(outerEle)
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to this:

```
For outerCount As Integer = 0 To liAllPolygons.Count - 1

        If outerCount > liAllPolygons.Count - 1 Then Exit For

        For innerCount As Integer = 0 To liAllPolygons.Count - 1

            If innerCount > liAllPolygons.Count - 1 Then Exit For

            If liAllPolygons(outerCount).Equals(liAllPolygons(innerCount)) Then Continue For
            If ClsMath.AreTwoPolygonsIdentical2(liAllPolygons(outerCount).Nodes, liAllPolygons(innerCount).Nodes) Then
                liAllPolygons.RemoveAt(innerCount)
                'GoTo Reset
            End If
        Next
    Next
```